# Why Can't I Use "Struct" As A Type in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

I am creating a `struct` and want to have a nested `struct` inside it.

This is what it looks like:

```
public struct TGObject: Codable {
    var metadata: Struct
    var image: TGImage

    public init(image: TGImage, metadata: Struct) {
        self.image = image
        self.metadata = metadata
    }
}
```

The problem is Xcode does not allow me to use `Struct` as a type. Why is that? Why could I use `String` or `Int` as a type, yet Struct is not acceptable. The reason I want `Struct` as the type is that the user should be able to create their own `struct` and drop it in the `init` for this one.

Aka:

```
struct metadataStruct {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
}
let metadataInstance = metadataStruct(name: "John")
let imageInstance = TGObject(image: "image.com")
var structInstance = TGObject(image: imageInstance, metadata: metadataInstance)
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: Because there's no generic type called `Struct`. Such as there's no generic type called `Class`.

Comment: What would you expect `MemoryLayout<TGObject>.size` to be?

Comment: @Hamish i'm a little confused by that question. if you are asking about size then it would be pretty small

Comment: @DávidPásztor is there any way to get around it? (allow a user to put their own struct into mine?)

Comment: @TheoStrauss My point is that the memory size of a struct needs to be known at compile time. Sounds like you just want generics, e.g `public struct TGObject<T>: Codable { var metadata: T ...`

Comment: You guys are overthinking this. All OP needs is generics.

Comment: I think you were describing [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. As Dávid Pásztor mentioned there is no such type as Struct.
I would suggest you to use a Dictionary as a type for metadata. So users will be able to put keys and values to the metadata and pass them to your constructor.

```
public struct TGObject: Codable {
    var metadata: [String:Any]
    var image: TGImage

    public init(image: TGImage, metadata: [String:Any]) {
        self.image = image
        self.metadata = metadata

        let someInfo = metadata["Key"]
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to give this one the check mark. why did it get a downvote?

Comment: Because this is a hacky solution. Swift has types; use them.

Comment: @NRitH yeah but i do need mine to be a dictionary or struct because its going into a json object. its a very smart idea. yours is too but it doesnt accomplish exactly what i want. thank you so much though for your answer

Comment: @NRitH i agree that your answer is better in general, but for the author's question, i think my answer suites better. Because he needs a list of values passed by users

Comment: But my answer *will* work with a dictionary, too, or any other type, without changing any part of the struct's declaration. If you pass in `["key" : Foo()]` as the metadata, then the `TGObject` will do exactly what you expect.

Comment: @NRitH thats the problem: it shouldnt work with any type. my server would reject a string or an int, it needs it formatted in a certain way and thats why i liked having a struct or a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the invalid type name `Struct`, make it a generic type, like so:

```
public struct TGObject<MetadataType>: Codable {
    var metadata: MetadataType
    var image: TGImage

    public init(image: TGImage, metadata: MetadataType) {
        self.image = image
        self.metadata = metadata
    }
}
```

Now you can use it with any type, like

```
let image = UIImage(...)
let metadata = "This is going to be a string."
let object = TGObject(image: image, metadata: metadata)
```

Comment: although, i checkmarked the other answer, it might have not turned out correct. because i am trying to encode the metadata, it needs to know the type and it cannot be "any". but, your answer is still not correct either as they you proved with your solution they can send a string as metadata. because i need to send json, the metadata HAS TO BE a dictionary. can you adjust your answer to suit that need? ill definitely give you the check mark then

Comment: I'm still not sure that you understand what my answer is saying. With my answer, your metadata type can be ANYTHING. All you have to do is change the metadata type that you pass into it, which sounds like what your original question was looking for. Want metadata to be a dictionary? You don't have to touch your `TGObject` struct; just pass a different type as the `metadata` argument. Whatever you pass into the constructor becomes the type that the `TGObject`'s metadata is bound to.

Comment: Yes but I am not passing the type as the metadata argument. i am creating a framework that people use and _they_ create metadata. with your current answer, they can pass in ANYTHING and the server would reject most of it. it needs correctly formatted json which comes in the form of a struct/dictionary